# animation nodes random color setup not working

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to replicate the effect of random colors from this setup using set vertex color node:

[image]

but my setup is not working, it just changes the color of the original object:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution but it only works in the render view.

Inside the cycles material I just had to plug the vertex color in the color on the material using the attribute node (input/attribute) and it works!!!

[image: random material color]

Comment: Please accept your answer if it answers the question.